# Spring Environment Variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was planning to use `@Value` annotation to my service implementation class.

```
 @Value("${some_property:default_value}")
 private String key;
```

To use above annotation, I can use `@Autowired`annotation.

```
 @Autowird
 Private Environment environment;
```

But, I am planning to use those setting in my `applicationContext.xml` file, which is something like following below.

```
<context: something missing here = "ENVIRONMENT"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. You can do it  in `applicationContext.xml` `beans` tag itself there is a property called `profile` So you can do  `profile="ENVIRONMENT"` in latest spring version.